# Is there a name for the integer $x$ that generates the set of real numbers $\{\frac{x}{10^i},i \ge 0\}$

Tags: notation, real-numbers, integers

> Is there a name for the integer $x$ that generates the set of real numbers $\{\frac{x}{10^i},i \ge 0\}$ (excluding zeroes at the left)? Context: I am working in a generalization of the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and I would like to express that concept. For now I am calling it the "template" integer of the set, but I guess that there is already a name for it, but I can not recall it.

E.g.: $142536$ is the "template" integer for:

$$142536$$
$$14253,6$$
$$1425,36$$
$$142,536$$
$$14,2536$$
$$1,42536$$
$$0,142536$$
$$0,0142536$$
$$0,00142536$$
$$\cdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the *mantissa* or [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) as Wikipedia calls it?